# Magento: Observer for order state is complete

Tags: magento

On Magento, I am developing a commission module which I need to pay my agents when the sales is completed and not when the order is placed.

Ideally I would want to capture it when the order state turns into 'complete' but I have not found an observer to do this ?

I could add this to the shipment observer but a order can have multiple shipment and hence not right.

Alternatively I could always fire a cron job to calculate the order for last hour but again does not seem the right way.

Any suggestions on what is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the observer "sales_order_save_commit_after" or "sales_order_invoice_pay" then you can get the order status and depending on the status you do what you want. Here is an example:

```
// for event sales_order_save_commit_after
public function commissionCalculationOnComplete($observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE){
    // do your order complete stuff
    }
}
```

or

```
// Event sales_order_invoice_pay
public function triggerProvisionCalculation ($observer)
{
    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
    switch ($invoice->getState()) {
        case Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::STATE_PAID :
            //do your stuff
            break;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

You will have to check that you don't do the calculation twice, because this method is triggered each time an order is saved.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question: Should I use sales_order_save_commit_after or sales_order_save_after ? I could not find where these were being called when I do a 'grep -ri' on /app/code/core.

Comment: the commit event is triggered from the Abstract Model while saving, it's in the method afterCommitCallback() `Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_commit_after', $this->_getEventData());`.

Comment: the difference between both events is for the commit event, you can do your logic after the commit is done in the database. It means if you are saving an order and use the event after the commit, your database is up to date. It's useful if your need information from the database and not directly from the object and you want to be sure that everything is ok in the db.
If you use the event ´sales_order_save_after´, the object $order may be ok but the statement of your database is still locked by a transaction and an error can occur and the integrity of your data could be unstable.

Comment: Thanks Diglin. The expanations helps a lot. As you suggested it makes maximum sense to use commit_after to make sure the database is not locked. Lot of thanks for the quick and apt response.

Comment: The `sales_order_invoice_save_after` event is *probably* the better choice for this use.

Comment: @Jongosi What if you need to really need to know that the order is Complete to perform your logic? I think it is safe to watch the state of the order rather than invoice payment. I might choose to cancel the order and refund the customer. This means I have to do a lot of house keeping to put everything back in order.

Comment: @SylvainRayé How to get State?

Answer (score 0):

**magento order complete and cancel quantity changes on incre and decre on database observer
**
Zero/SalesOderafter/config.xml

```
    <config>
    <modules>
   <Zero_SalesOrderafter>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
  </Zero_SalesOrderafter>
  </modules>
  <global>
   <events>
   <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                 <ordercancel>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Zero_SalesOrderafter_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>canCancelOrder</method>
                 </ordercancel>
            </observers>
     </sales_order_save_after>
   </events>
   </global>
    </config>

 path:Zero/SalesOrderafter/Observer.php
  class Wli_SalesOrderafter_Model_Observer 
   {
  public function canCancelOrder( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
  { 
     $data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
   if($data->getId())
    {
     $ProdustIds=array();
    foreach ($data->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
     {
      $ProdustIds= $item->getProductId();
      }        
     } 
      $qty = $data->getData('total_qty_ordered');
      $order_status = $data->getStatus();
      $incrementId = $data->getData('increment_id');
    }       

     }
     ?>
```